# Adding a title to a ul in the menus

Tags: 7, routes

I need to create the following to a menu system in drupal 7. I want to be able to create a href that is not connected to a content type. Is this possible?

```
<ul> 
  <li>link</li>
 <li>link </li>
 <li> 
<ul><a href ='#' class="dropdown">I need this link to not be attached to a content type</a>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attached to content type"? Links can be given by node id or by path, and may as well be external. And could you make question's title and body match? Now I fail to see a connection between them.

Answer (score 0):

try this module "[Nice Menus](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus)" and this "[Menu Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)".

You can follow these tutorials for more informations:
http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-menu-attributes-module
http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-nice-menus-module

I hope it helps you out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to fix this issue,

**special_menu_items module**
This allows me to nolink so I could create a href="#"

**menu_attributes  module** 
To add an id